# REACT-APP Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

whenever i try to make print it out on a browser i always get the error on the header
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"
before asking this question i tried all solutions similar to this problem including adding "type":"module", to my json package but none seems to work,i also added the "pack" and still no print out all my scripts are properly configured i use ecma6script and the latest version of react as well,

here is my hmtl code below

````
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="indexx.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>```

and here is my reactcode

```import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

ReactDom.render(<h1>hello world</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));```


  below is my json package

```{
  "name": "asa-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}```
````

Comment: that doesnt look like it can compile. Or have you formatted your code snippets incorrectly?

Comment: 1) What does `<script src="indexx.js"></script>` mean? Shouldn't it be `index.js` instead of `indexx.js`?
2) Sounds like you try to open not compiled code on browser. What happens when you start dev mode (`npm start` or `yarn start` in command like from app root)?

Comment: i renamed the index file to indexx inorder to avoid confusion because i was initially thinking it may try to link to my other index.js files moreover its just a name ,i guess it shouldnt be a problem, and why doesnt it look like it can compile?

Comment: when i run (npm start) the server begins normally, all npm functions are working normally|)

Comment: Replied in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to launch not compiled sources directly from a browser. To launch a workable app you can do:

1. `npm start` - DEV server launched on localhost:3000
2. `npm run build` - PROD build, compiles the sources into the `build/` folder. There you'll find compiled JS, CSS and index.html to launch.